# Floor function of a real number

Tags: number-theory

The floor of a real number $x$, denoted by $⌊x⌋$, is the largest integer that is less than or equal to $x$. The ceiling of a real number x, denoted by $⌈x⌉$, is the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to $x$. Let $x$ and $y$ be any real numbers. Let $n, m$ and $k$ be any integers.

1. $⌊x⌋ \le x < ⌊x⌋+1$, equivalently $x-1 < ⌊x⌋ \le x$.
2. $⌈x⌉-1 < x \le ⌈x⌉$, equivalently $x \le ⌈x⌉ < x+1$.
3. If $n \le x < n+1$ (or $x-1 < n \le x$), then $n=⌊x⌋$; similarly, if $n-1 < x \le n$ (or $x \le n < x+1$), then $n=⌈x⌉$.
4. If $x \le y$, then $⌊x⌋ \le ⌊y⌋$ and $⌈x⌉ \le ⌈y⌉$. Similarly for $x \ge y$.
5. If $n \le x$, then $n \le ⌊x⌋$. If $n \ge x$, then $n \ge ⌈x⌉$.
6. If $x$ has an integer value, then $⌊x⌋=x=⌈x⌉$. If x has a non-integer value, then $⌈x⌉=⌊x⌋+1$.

Furthermore, we have the well-known inequality: $ \frac {x-1}{x} \le \ln x \le \frac {x^2 -1}{2x} \le x-1$
I am trying to find all pairs of positive real numbers $(x,y)$ such that $ \ln⁡(⌊x+y⌋ )=⌊y⌋+⌊x⌋,$ but the above identities are hard to follow. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\lfloor \ln(x + y)\rfloor = ⌊y⌋+⌊x⌋$ or $⌊\ln (⌊y⌋+⌊x⌋)⌋ = ⌊y⌋+⌊x⌋$.  $⌊y⌋+⌊x⌋$ must be an integer but $\ln (integer) $ seldom an integer.  $\ln (integer_x) = integer_y$ means $integer_x = 1$ and $integer_y = 0$ and that would work if $1 \le x  +y < 2$ but $0< x < 1; 0< y< 1$  Which will solve the problem you stated but doesn't do what I think you want it to do.

Answer (score 7):

> The following does **not** use the fact that $e$ is transcendental.

First , note that $$\tag 1\lfloor x+y\rfloor \le\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor +1$$ 
for all real $x,y$.

Take the exponential of both sides of teh target equation to arrive at the equivalent condition
$$ \lfloor x+y\rfloor =e^{\lfloor x\rfloor}e^{\lfloor y\rfloor}$$
Using the mother of all $e$-inequalities, 
$$\tag{$\star$} e^t\ge 1+t\qquad\text{with equality iff }t=0,$$
we find (as $x,y$ are positive by assumption) 
$$\tag2 \begin{align}\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor +1&\ge \lfloor x+y\rfloor \\&=e^{\lfloor x\rfloor} e^{\lfloor y\rfloor}\\&\ge(1+\lfloor x\rfloor)(1+\lfloor y\rfloor)\\&=1+\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor +\lfloor x\rfloor\lfloor y\rfloor\end{align}$$
so that we must have $\lfloor x\rfloor\lfloor y\rfloor =0$ and the inequality in $(2)$ is sharp. by the sharpness condition in $(\star)$, we conclude that $$\lfloor x\rfloor =\lfloor y\rfloor=0$$
and by exploiting $(2)$, now an equality,
$$ \lfloor x+y\rfloor =\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor  y\rfloor +1=1.$$
hence a **necessary** condition is that $$\fbox{$\quad0\le x<1, \quad 0\le y<1, \quad1\le x+y.\quad\vphantom\int$}$$
As this implies $x+y<2$, we see immediately that these are also **sufficient** as we compute $\ln\lfloor x+y\rfloor=\ln 1=0$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor = 0+0=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the right side is an integer so the left side must be, too.  That means $\lfloor x+y\rfloor$ is an integer power of $e$ but it is also an integer, so it must be $1$ and the $\log$ is $0$.  This gives
$$\lfloor x+y\rfloor=1\\ \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor=0$$
If either $x$ or $y$ is greater than or equal to $1$ the second will fail, so our final solution is $$0 \lt x \lt 1\\ 1-x \lt y \lt 1$$
or the part of the unit square above $x+y=1$  It is the region strictly inside the triangle below
[image]

Comment: @Dzoooks:  the question calls for both $x$ and $y$ to be positive.  Otherwise we could add any integer to an $x$ in this region and subtract the same integer from $y$ to get more solutions.

Comment: You're right.  This is a "fundamental domain" for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two cases for positive reals $x$ and $y$. Note that we require $x + y \geq 1$ for the left side of the equation to be defined, so we make this assumption.

- If $x,y < 1$, then the equation holds, as both sides are equal to zero.
- If $x \geq 1$, then suppose the equality holds, so that $e^{\lfloor x \rfloor}e^{\lfloor y \rfloor} =\lfloor x + y \rfloor$. Since $x \geq 1$, $e^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is not an integer, hence the left side is not an integer, a contradiction since the right side is. Similar when $y \geq 1$.

Thus, the only positive real solutions $(x,y)$ are characterized by the first case.